# SSRS ReportServer Database. Query snapshot data in SQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is there a way Query Snapshot (Report History) data in SQL using ReportServer Database. I know we can retrieve the RDL using the Catalog content. Is the way to retrieve the snapshot data in SQL?

```
SELECT t1.ReportID,
    t2.SnapshotDataID,
    t2.Path,
    CONVERT (VARBINARY(MAX), t2.Content) AS Content,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT (VARBINARY(MAX), t2.Content)) AS ContentVarchar,
    CONVERT (XML, CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT (VARBINARY(MAX), t2.Content))) AS ContentXML
FROM ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLogStorage t1
INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog t2 ON t1.ReportID = t2.ItemID
WHERE DATEADD (DD, 0, DATEDIFF (DD, 0, t1.TimeStart)) = DATEADD (DD, 0, DATEDIFF (DD, 0, GETDATE ()))
ORDER BY t1.TimeStart DESC;
```

Comment: Are you looking for the snapshot history?  http://www.chilledsql.com/welcome/tip_category_reportsandssrs/tip_detail_ssrs_getreportsnapshothistory

Comment: @devlincarnate I am also looking to query the data in each report history. Not just a list of list of snapshot that were created.

Comment: according to MS, you're supposed to use their web API for this type of query, although it doesn't look like their API documentation gives an example of how to query snapshot data.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155071.aspx